# Sending a Refresh() to WMI in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi, performancecounter

In a PowerShell script I am trying to get the number of page faults per second with this command:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_memory).PageFaultsPersec
```

Unfortunately, it reads always the same value because I don't Refresh() the performance counter.

How can I send a Refresh() method to Performance Data via PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value using performance counters:

```
Get-Counter '\Memory\Page Faults/sec'
```

However, if I call you code in a loop, it works without problems (although it is better practise to first store the wmi object).

```
1..10 | % { sleep -sec 2; (Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_memory).PageFaultsPersec }
```

Comment: Glad to help. I've seen many people to try refresh the wmi perf counters but nobody who succeeded :|